# Dictionary For Loop for Scoring Word

Tags: python-3.x

I am creating a program that scores a scrabble game.  For the part that scores the word, it uses a dictionary with the Scrabble letter values:

```py
letter_val = {" ": 0, "a": "1", "b": 3, "c": 3, "d": 2, "e": 1, "f": 4, "g": 2, "h": 4, "i": 1, "j": 8, "k": 5, "l": 1, "m": 3, "n": 1, "o": 1, "p": 3, "q": 10, "r": 1, "s": 1, "t": 1, "u": 1, "v": 4, "w": 4, "x": 8, "y": 4, "z": 10}
```

It takes a word as input and loops through it with the dictionary, assigning the sum to a value.  I tried something along the lines of:

```
value = sum(letter_val[i.lower() for i in word])
```

or just:

```
value = letter_val[i.lower() for i in word
```

Will I have to make a whole for loop or is there anything I'm missing in the way I'm doing it?

Comment: 1. `sum(letter_val[i.lower()] for i in word)` 2. Fix the score for the letter `a` (should be a number not a string)

Comment: Ok thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

When you iterate through a string/list inline, it returns an array.

```
>>> x = "many"
>>> y = [i for i in x]
>>> y
['m', 'a', 'n', 'y']
```

While looking up a value in a dictionary, it's done just like index based accessing on a list.

```
>>> a = {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z": 3}
>>> b = a["x"]
>>> b
1
```

In your case, you're putting together both of the above. 
So, first off, make a list from the scores equivalent to the letters in the word

```
>>> letter_val = {" ": 0, "a": 1, "b": 3, "c": 3, "d": 2, "e": 1, "f": 4, "g": 2, "h": 4, "i": 1, "j": 8, "k": 5, "l": 1, "m": 3, "n": 1, "o": 1, "p": 3, "q": 10, "r": 1, "s": 1, "t": 1, "u": 1, "v": 4, "w": 4, "x": 8, "y": 4, "z": 10}
>>> word = "abc"
>>> scores = [letter_val[i] for i in word]
>>> scores
[1, 3, 3]
```

Then find the sum of values of the list

```
>>> value = sum(scores)
>>> value
7
```